# When using Firebase Extension "Export to BigQuery" is the export free or is it charged as streaming inserts?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I want to use Export to BigQuery extension, and i'd like to know if this export is charged as "streaming inserts"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both collection mirroring and initial import operations (using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebaseextensions/fs-bq-import-collection) are implemented with a call to the bigquery streaming inserts API (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) and billed as such.